# Need to modify this Java program to print only one iteration of each prime factor

Tags: java

I have a Java program "Factors" which takes a command line argument and print its prime factors. For example, if you run the program with the argument 3757208, it will print 2 2 2 7 13 13 397. I need to modify the code so that each prime factor is printed only one time. So with the above example, my desired outcome is 2 7 13 397. Thank you! Here is the code:

```
public class Factors
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { // Print the prime factors of N.        
        long N = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
        long n = N;
        for (long i = 2; i*i <= n; i++) 
        { // Test whether i is a factor.
            while (n % i == 0) 
            { // Cast out and print i factors                 
                n = n / i;
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
        }
        // if biggest factor occurs only once, n > 1
        if (n > 1) System.out.println(n);
        else       System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: We're not here to do your job/homework/test for you.

Comment: It's not like I haven't been trying on my own, I'm just stumped and could use some help.

Comment: @MarcB Have you seen this yet? http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/ We were all new once, too.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of printing the number as you find it, you could add it to a `Set`, and then print your `Set` after the loop. That would automatically get rid of the duplicates.

Comment: thank you for your help. we haven't covered sets yet in class, but I see what you're saying.

Comment: I'd discourage the use of a Set in this context. Unnecessary memory usage. however, it's not like it's going to make any difference, considering we're talking about java :/

Comment: @AndreasHenning: The memory used to store the found different factors is next to nothing for all practical usages of this program.

Comment: @Keppil still, it's unnecessary. :)  [I know, I know. I'm not thinking Java-esque here]

Answer (score 0):

you could just do

```
if(n % i == 0)
    System.out.println(i + " ");
while(n % i == 0)
    n /= i;
```

instead of

```
while (n % i == 0) 
{ // Cast out and print i factors                 
    n = n / i;
    System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

Comment: thank you! I figured i needed to play around with an if statement. This helps a lot

Comment: @Keppil what outer while loop? O_o

Comment: I think he means the for loop?